# Regenerate state after a server crash

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a solution for "state regeneration" of a web app after a crash. 
For example, my app is able to create invoices, and is using an idCounter for numbering these invoices. If the app crashes, the last invoiceNr need to be fetched from the DB and used to reset the idCounter.

In my route module, I have code that looks like this:

```
var idCounter = null;

db.invoices.findOne({}, null, {sort: {'invoiceNr': -1}}, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    idCounter = doc.invoiceNr;
});
```

This works well, but I'm concerned that the icCounter is set trough a callback, which means (in theory) a user can trigger some code that need the idCounter (Like creating a new invoice) BEFORE the callback is triggered, and therefore get the wrong variable...

What kind of pattern do you use for "state regeneration" after a web app crashes?

Comment: Use this on startup, and don't initialise the main app (which might create invoices at any time) before it is done.

Comment: You shouldn't need to maintain an `idCounter` in your app. This job should be done by your database.

Comment: @Bergi: Ok, but if I dont maintain an icCounter in my app, the I have to fetch the latest invoice (to get the latest nr) at every "create new invoice" operation... Then i need two querys every time i create an invoice instead of one, but do you still think that is better?
Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: No, I say that your database should have a method to auto-create incrementing ids in insert operations.